# Frequency Distribution and Throughput

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am conducting an experiment on a couple of computer systems but the results I have don't make sense to me.
I made each system perform 1000 operations:

System A performs operations at a rate of `476/second`

System B performs operations at a rate of `88/second`

But when I look at the frequency distribution of the operations, the large gap in the throughput does not make sense to me:

```
Time(s) B   A
<1      908 0
1-3     84  977
4-6     3   13
7-9     2   7
10-12   2   2
13-15   1   0
16-18   0   0
19-21   0   0
22-24   0   0
25-27   0   0
28-30   0   1
31-33   0   0
34-36   0   0
37-39   0   0
40+     0   0
```

As  you can see system B performed 90% of its operations in under a second, while system A performed 97% in 1-3 seconds. I would have expected to see a much larger spread of operations in system B than in system A given the huge difference in throughput both systems have.

Do my results make sense?

Comment: Are the two machine performing the same operations?  How do you determine how many operations per second each machine is capable of?

Comment: Yes, each machine is performing the same operations. I am using benchmarking software that measures the throughout(operations/second)

Comment: Something is certainly amiss then because system A takes longer to do the same operations, so it cannot have a faster operation rate.

Comment: On an aside, I'm not confident that there is much/any math involved here... your question may be more appropriate for another site.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possible points of confusion here that I
hardly know where to start.

First, I wonder what 'time' means in your tabulation.
It can hardly be seconds. If the rate is 88/sec. then
how can there possibly be 908 within the first second.

Second, one might suppose 'rates' refer to rates of
exponential distributions. But then there is no possibility
of having zero outcomes within the first second, and many in the
following two seconds.

So I conclude that the units are likely inconsistent and
the times for individual operations cannot be exponentially
distributed.

On this site one supposes a probability model lies behind
the question, but from the information you provide, I have
no idea what that model might be.

From my own (limited) experience with benchmarking software,
I suspect there is more to the "speed" of these machines
than the quoted rates. Could  there some competing process
running in the background? Different interfaces? Viruses?

Unless you can provide clarifications and additional information,
I doubt you will get a more helpful answer here?